# Allow outer variable inside Julia's sort comparison

Tags: sorting, julia

The issue:

I want to be able to sort with a custom function that depends on an outer defined variable, for example:

```
k = 2
sort([1,2,3], lt=(x,y) -> x + k > y)
```

This works all dandy and such because `k` is defined in the global scope.

That's where my issue lays, as I want to do something akin to:

```
function 
    k = 2
    comp = (x,y) -> x + k > y
    sort([1,3,3], lt=comp)
end
```

Which works, but feels like a hack, because my comparison function is way bigger and it feels really off to have to have it defined there in the body of the function.

For instance, this wouldn't work:

```
comp = (x,y) -> x + k > y # or function comp(x,y) ... end
function 
    k = 2
    sort([1,3,3], lt=comp)
end
```

So I'm just wondering if there's any way to capture variables such as `k` like you'd be able to do with lambda functions in `C++`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
julia> comp(k) = (x,y) -> x + k > y
comp (generic function with 1 method)

julia> sort([1,3,2,3,2,2,2,3], lt=comp(2))
8-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
 2
 2
 2
 3
 2
 3
 1
```

Comment: Oh, brilliant! Next time I'll try to keep the [fundamental theorem of software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering) in mind.

Comment: Julia is really convenient for creating closures. You probably know that in a similar way you can perform partial function application e.g. by writing `>(2)` (which defines a function taking one argument and comparing it to `2`).

Comment: I didn't, nor I understand the syntax. Where can I read more about it?

Comment: just read help of e.g. `>`.

Comment: @DMeneses or google "partial application".